# How can I get the sites name data from JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can I get the `sites name` data value, with entire `Formdata` array?

Expected output:

```
["TEST-TRIAL-001120", 
 "Mubashir Test Site - 001001", 
 "TEST-TRIAL-001120", 
 "TEST SITE -001"]
```

```js
const Formdata = [{
    "id": "6efcf3f7-5d29-4a88-8ce9-346229a86765",
    "title": "Deepak test form 2",
    "version": "1",
    "sites": [{
      "id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b",
      "name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120"
    }],
    "status": "Not Linked"
  },
  {
    "id": "89e5a12d-913d-4f5d-a030-b172af9e27f0",
    "title": "Deepak Test form 1",
    "version": "1",
    "sites": [],
    "status": "Not Linked"
  },
  {
    "id": "79a15768-762e-4ff8-b565-31274a38b22d",
    "title": "1.7 Form",
    "version": "1",
    "sites": [{
      "id": "32369d1d-f247-4a75-8c14-490c8393dbb8",
      "name": "Mubashir Test Site - 001001"
    }, {
      "id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b",
      "name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120"
    }, {
      "id": "a6526163-3ed7-4125-8f32-e0066fc6fe24",
      "name": "TEST SITE -001"
    }],
    "status": "Not Linked"
  }
]
Formdata.map(form => {
  console.log(form.sites); //not understand how to get sites name data value
});
```

Comment: You're logging literal text. You need `console.log(form.sites);`

Comment: Can you elaborate on your expected output? A JavaScript object is a key-value store, not an array of strings. Did you mean to use square brackets instead?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) sorry mybad

Comment: I only show the sites name in ouput. [https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew)

Comment: If you want to respond to a user, use `@` and their user name. Type `@` and the first three letters or so, then Tab, and it should auto complete. For instance, type `@her<Tab>` and it should autocomplete `@HereticMonkey` (without code formatting, which I've added here for illustration), which will alert me that you've responded to me. A link to my user profile will not do that.

Comment: I fixed your output. You cannot have an object of strings

Answer (score 1):

I use the [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const Formdata = [{ "id": "6efcf3f7-5d29-4a88-8ce9-346229a86765", "title": "Deepak test form 2", "version": "1", "sites": [{ "id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b", "name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120" }], "status": "Not Linked" }, { "id": "89e5a12d-913d-4f5d-a030-b172af9e27f0", "title": "Deepak Test form 1", "version": "1", "sites": [], "status": "Not Linked" }, { "id": "79a15768-762e-4ff8-b565-31274a38b22d", "title": "1.7 Form", "version": "1", "sites": [{ "id": "32369d1d-f247-4a75-8c14-490c8393dbb8", "name": "Mubashir Test Site - 001001" }, { "id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b", "name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120" }, { "id": "a6526163-3ed7-4125-8f32-e0066fc6fe24", "name": "TEST SITE -001" }], "status": "Not Linked" } ];

const sites = Formdata.flatMap(({sites}) => sites.map(({name}) => name))


console.log(sites)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response [https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Comment: @Andy Oops. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the site array to get an array of names, [then flattening that array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const Formdata=[{id:"6efcf3f7-5d29-4a88-8ce9-346229a86765",title:"Deepak test form 2",version:"1",sites:[{id:"d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b",name:"TEST-TRIAL-001120"}],status:"Not Linked"},{id:"89e5a12d-913d-4f5d-a030-b172af9e27f0",title:"Deepak Test form 1",version:"1",sites:[],status:"Not Linked"},{id:"79a15768-762e-4ff8-b565-31274a38b22d",title:"1.7 Form",version:"1",sites:[{id:"32369d1d-f247-4a75-8c14-490c8393dbb8",name:"Mubashir Test Site - 001001"},{id:"d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b",name:"TEST-TRIAL-001120"},{id:"a6526163-3ed7-4125-8f32-e0066fc6fe24",name:"TEST SITE -001"}],status:"Not Linked"}];

const result = Formdata.flatMap(({ sites }) => {
  return sites.map(({ name }) => name);
});

console.log(result);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

First `map` the sites names from each form. This leaves you with an array of arrays which you need to flatten, which can be done with `concat` or `flatMap`

```js
const Formdata = [{"id": "6efcf3f7-5d29-4a88-8ce9-346229a86765","title": "Deepak test form 2","version": "1","sites": [{"id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b","name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120"}],"status": "Not Linked"},{"id": "89e5a12d-913d-4f5d-a030-b172af9e27f0","title": "Deepak Test form 1","version": "1","sites": [], "status": "Not Linked"},{"id": "79a15768-762e-4ff8-b565-31274a38b22d","title": "1.7 Form","version": "1","sites": [{"id": "32369d1d-f247-4a75-8c14-490c8393dbb8","name": "Mubashir Test Site - 001001"}, {"id": "d7f2b290-2820-401a-a347-9a4dd05ec02b","name": "TEST-TRIAL-001120"}, {"id": "a6526163-3ed7-4125-8f32-e0066fc6fe24","name": "TEST SITE -001"}],"status": "Not Linked"}]

let sites = [].concat.apply([],
  Formdata.map(data =>
    data.sites.map(site => site.name)
  )
)
/*let sites = Formdata.map(data =>
    data.sites.map(site => site.name)
  ).flatMap(x=>x)*/
console.log(sites)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3462319/depperm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3462319/depperm)